# Multiple return statements inside function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I was building a React app and came across a certain code block where there were multiple return inside a function. Could anyone help me to understand how the control of the program would be for the following snippet? Thanks

```
const result = (input) => {
        return fetch(
            `${url}`
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                return {
                    options: response.data.map((city) => {
                        return {
                            value: `${city.latitude} ${city.longitude}`,
                            label: `${city.name}, ${city.countryCode}`,
                        };
                    }),
                };
            });
    };
```

Comment: There are 4 functions in this snippet

Comment: And only one return statement from the result function.

Comment: you can use `async/await` to handle it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score -1):

It's a function with functions inside.
In javascript you can define functions in functions, and pass anonymous [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as parameters too.

Array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) routine also take a function as first argument, in your case the argument is the function:

```js
(city) => {
  return {
    value: `${city.latitude} ${city.longitude}`,
    label: `${city.name}, ${city.countryCode}`,
  };
}
```

This kind of notation (accumulating `.then()` and subfunctions is called [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Note that this snippet is the same result function as yours.

```js
  const result = async (input) => {
    const response = (await fetch(`${url}`))?.json();
    return {
      options: response?.data?.map((city) => ({
        value: `${city.latitude} ${city.longitude}`,
        label: `${city.name}, ${city.countryCode}`
      }))
    };
  };
```

Comment: Why so many `?.`?

Comment: Where do you see "many" `?.` (optional chaining notation) ?
Only the good number are present, not much, not less

Comment: `(await fetch(`${url}`))` is guaranteed to return a value so `?`. is unnecessary, same with `response` and `data`. Neither of these can be `undefined`

Comment: We dont know if he's using fetch API from node 18+ or a custom node-fetch or other package, so in case...
And response.data can be a non array value where map doesn't exist

Comment: Adding `?.` everywhere is voodoo coding. `node-fetch` also always return a response and never `undefined`

Comment: like I said, "or another package creating a routine named `fetch`", a lot do exists with that name (function, not package).
And it's not really "voodoo coding", yes on the principe but the compiler (for typescript) isn't dummy, it make optimizations so the code do have optional chaining but compiled result is clear (so stable). And optional chaining's results are just:
`variable === null || variable === void 0 ? void 0 : variable.attribute`, it's not hard to interpret. puting `await` keyword everywhere is more "voodoo coding" than optional chaining.